# Javascript for putting new content in a div upon click - automatically scrolling down to new content isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autoscroll

Here's the code that I'm using. I want the user to be able to click on the flowers, and to have them automatically be scrolled down to the div where the larger flowers pops up. Sometimes it does this, sometimes it goes down for a split second and goes back up. What's wrong? Here's the site in action, but you have to wait a bit for the images to load:

http://www.momentaryvitality.ca/prairie2.shtml

```
function updateContainer(url) {
    dynamicCon = '#dynamicContainer';
    ObjTag = $(dynamicCon);
    ObjTag.load(url);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[rel="dynamicLoad"]').bind("click", function (event) {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        updateContainer(url);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: note that if you debug the code e.g. in chromium, you'll see 
prairie2.shtml:81Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined. you need to define height before at least

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the javascript console, you will see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined
```

Which points to this line of code:

```
    ({
        scrollTop: height
    }, 3000);
```

Which does nothing, and it uses an undefined variable to do that nothing.  And sadly, your intent is somewhat unclear, but I'd start with fixing those 2 problems.

Comment: That was an ill-fated attempt to do what I want. When the user clicks on a flower, and that brings up a larger version of that flower in the div below, I want the script to automatically scroll down to that div.

Comment: ok, that's fixed, so how would I go about making it scroll down successfully?

Comment: How did you fix it? Please update your question with the current code. And be sure to run it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ so we can actually read it.

Comment: I deleted the broken scrollTop part.

Comment: So what do I do now to scroll down automatically on each click?